# How to create a windows installer for python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pyinstaller

I've found several answers for this subject on stackoverflow but I'd like to reiterate. 
I created a small gui application in python that uses Tkinter (if that matters), uses icons and separate text files with configuration rules and other resources.

So basically, there is one executable .py script, a bunch of text files and gif icons. 
I need to create an installer for windows. I have never tried to make an installer before, but considering using NSIS. 
What installer serves best for such setup?

Comment: http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I want to make an installation file for my python source code"**

You have to use NSIS, InnoSetup, BitRock Installer, IzPack or equivalent to produce a platform installer. So you have to take the binary result produced on the first part and package it for os distribution. Almost all the installer systems are thinked for Windows systems. Cross platform : Zero Install, IzPack ... If you use IzPack you can have a cross platform installer paying the price of including a jvm.

And i Believe This >> [HELP](http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/) Can be Light of Your Way ;)

Comment: what about pyinstaller?

Comment: Combine py2exe and an installer wizard, like NSIS, and you are done.